# Take a screenshot of a URL provided

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I want to take a screenshot of an URL given.

I have found several other examples, but, theses takes screenshots of the current page (Same page the JQuery lies).

1. Feedback JS (http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/)
2. html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
3. Another example (http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/10/webpage-screenshot-with-html5-js/)

There are many SO Posts related to getting screenshot of a site from the backend but, I want to take the screenshot from the client side (This is because the user may be logged in to his/her profile and the screenshot will contain those information if the client side generated the screenshot. If the server takes the screenshot then the information contained in the website cann't be taken)

However, none of these example helps me to sort the issue I have.

What I want to be done :

When a user provides a URL . I want to take generate a screen shot of that particular URL.

Note: My backend is on C#

Comment: Well you cannot capture a screenshot of another site using client-side JavaScript, consider the catastrophic privacy implications.

Comment: @AlexK. Google takes thumbnail pics of webpage visited. Anyway, this is possible, but I am not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Google can do many things as they likely wrote the browser.

Comment: @AlexK. So do you suggest that this can't be done ?